# SQLite FTS4 snippet argument format

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on analyzing texts in RQDA and am using the Firefox SQLite Manager to access the database so that I can search files more easily. I've created and populated virtual table:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE texts USING fts4(filename, content)
```

Then I did a snippet search

```
SELECT snippet(texts, '_', '_', '...') FROM texts WHERE texts MATCH 'great OR Great';
```

This returns results where the snippet term is highlighted with an underscore.

My questions:

1. How do I implement the 6th argument (documentation) so to increase the snippet size? (I see a similar question on this but the response does not work.)
2. How can I get the MATCH return to also show the filename for the snippet (first column in my table.) So the format will be "filename", "snippet".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Okay so I figured out the answer to question #2: `SELECT filename, snippet(texts, '_', '_', '...') FROM texts WHERE texts MATCH 'great';`

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out! Documentation on 6th parameter was not so clear...

```
SELECT filename, snippet(texts, '_', '_', '...', -30, 30) FROM texts WHERE texts MATCH 'great OR Great';
```

This displays the filename and snippet with 30 words before and after search term.

Comment: how can I remove ellipsis at the first? how to show the response from the beginning?